# How can I get output in decimal instead of fraction?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a simple equation but I cannot get the answer with decimal, how can I do it? I want FS1 and FN1 with decimal.

```
angleS = 0;

angleN = 90;

verticaleq =  FS1*sin[angleS] + FN1*sin[angleN] == 196.12; 

horizontaleq = FS1*cos[angleS] == FN1*cos[angleN];

Solve[{verticaleq, horizontaleq}, {FS1, FN1}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be writing sin like that. You should be using a capital letter in the beginning. For example Sin. The code should be

```
angleS = 0;

angleN = 90;

verticaleq = FS1*Sin[angleS] + FN1*Sin[angleN] == 196.12;

horizontaleq = FS1*Cos[angleS] == FN1*Cos[angleN];

Solve[{verticaleq, horizontaleq}, {FS1, FN1}] // N
```

And now the result is in decimal form. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for